# C# drawing text

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing, font-size

```
gfx.DrawString(
    thisTempLabel.LabelText,
    new Font("Arial", (float)thisTempLabel.fontSize),
    Brushes.Black,
    new PointF(thisTempLabel.x, thisTempLabel.y)
    );
```

This works fine, except I store my font size (`thisTempLabel.fontSize`) in pixels.  I can't for the life of me work out how to convert them (probably impossible) or what to do to resolve this.

They come out sort of right, but not in the right position by a bit and a bit too big.

Precision is very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you're having might be that the [constructor you're using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/164w6x6z.aspx) expects the size to be in points:

```
public Font(FontFamily family, float emSize)
```

> `emSize`
>   Type: System.Single
>   The em-size, in points, of the new font.

It looks like you can [use a different overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141986.aspx) that takes `GraphicsUnit` parameter, which you can set to `GraphicsUnit.Pixel`:

```
gfx.DrawString(
    thisTempLabel.LabelText,
    new Font("Arial", (float)thisTempLabel.fontSize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel),
    Brushes.Black,
    new PointF(thisTempLabel.x, thisTempLabel.y)
);
```

Note that you're setting the em size, which is, roughly, the height of the "M" character.

Comment: Thanks!  How would I modify my code to use this?  I find msdn documentation confusing :S